# Creating a Robinson distribution map of several plant species in R - polygon errors and other issues

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

This is my first time with maps in ggplot. I need to create 90 distribution maps of plant species.

Thus I set the API to get the data from Plant of the World Online and the shp from World Geographical Scheme for Recording Plant Distributions https://github.com/tdwg/wgsrpd

```
require(kewr)#to connect to POWO APIs
 


#getting data from POWO

id.powo <- search_wcvp("Camellia japonica")
id.powo<- id.powo$results[[1]]$id

r <- lookup_powo(id.powo, distribution = TRUE)

native <- r$distribution$natives
introduced <- r$distribution$introduced

tdwg.native.name <- list()
for (i in 1:length(native)){
  tdwg.native.name[[i]]<- native[[i]]$name
}
tdwg.native.name <- unlist(tdwg.native.name)

col.native <- c("#B8DE95") #pastel green for native 


tdwg.introduced.name <- list()
for (i in 1:length(introduced)){
  tdwg.introduced.code[[i]]<- introduced[[i]]$name
}
tdwg.introduced.name <- unlist(tdwg.introduced.code)

#col.introduced <- c("#9F6CCC") #pastel violet  for introduced


#creating the map

install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("barnabywalker/bazr")
library(bazr)

I downloaded the shp from https://github.com/tdwg/wgsrpd and then loaded in r

tdwg_level3.shp<- read_sf("/Users/...d/wgsrpd-master/level3/level3.shp")

tdwg_level3.shp.robinson<- st_transform(tdwg_level3.shp,  crs ="+proj=robin +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs") 


ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = tdwg_level3.shp.robinson)
```

From here problems starts, polygons form nord pole overlap and there is no matching
[image]

In addition, the map looks crowded since the are for some region subregional division and there are isles that makes the map looks dirty. Lastly, there is no need for plotting antartica...

Thus, the desired output should look like this
[image: Distribution of the x species at country level]

this map has been build using this script https://gist.github.com/valentinitnelav/065af8eba2d9455d9407e5d3890f6f86

I need to produce like 100 maps, one for each species. I'm going to list the code id.powo in a data frame column and looping the code then.

id.powo.list<- c("17414550-1", "296290-1", "263221-1")

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You were very close! I'll answer your problems in turn, but first just to say that I've done this all in the terra package because I find it by far the most intuitive for spatial stuff.

```
require(terra)
require(tidyterra)
tdwg_level3.shp <- vect("/Users/...d/wgsrpd-master/level3/level3.shp")
```

1. Re the lines, this was occurring because sometimes when you reproject a polygon of the world, the new projection cuts the polygons in a slightly different place (in this case, the exact point between Russia/Alaska where the edge of the Russian polygon is cut off). The easiest workaround is just to trim your first polygon slightly before you reproject:

   ```
   tdwg_level3.shp <- crop(tdwg_level3.shp, extent(-179.9, 179.9, -90, 84))
   ```
2. Re the crowded looking map, this is easily fixed by setting both "color" and "fill" to be the same in ggplot, then the lines just blend in with the general colour:

   ```
   ggplot() + 
     geom_spatvector(data = tdwg_level3.shp.robinson, fill="grey70", colour="grey70")
   ```

   [World map with no boundary lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUTDX.png)

   If you want *some* lines (e.g. the distinctions of Level 1), then first you can aggregate the tdwg shapefile:

   ```
   tdwg_level3.shp.robinson,simple <- aggregate(tdwg_level3.shp.robinson, by="LEVEL2_COD")

   ggplot() + geom_spatvector(data = tdwg_level3.shp.robinson.simple)
   ```

   [World map with aggregate boundary lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEL9W.png)
3. Removing Antarctica's easy, just subset the shapefile:

   ```
   tdwg_level3_rob <-tdwg_level3_rob[tdwg_level3_rob$LEVEL3_NAM != "Antarctica",]
   ```
4. There was just a bit more to get the native/introduced ranges in. First, create new shapefiles for each:

   ```
   tdwg_level3_nat <- tdwg_level3.shp.robinson[tdwg_level3.shp.robinson$LEVEL3_NAM %in% tdwg.native.name]

   tdwg_level3_int <- tdwg_level3.shp.robinson[tdwg_level3.shp.robinson$LEVEL3_NAM %in% tdwg.introduced.name]
   ```

   Then bring it all together (you'll notice had to do a bit of fancy footwork to get the legend to work, but it all comes together):

   ```
   ggplot() + 
     geom_spatvector(data = tdwg_level3_rob, fill="grey70", colour="grey70")+
     geom_spatvector(data = tdwg_level3_nat, aes(fill="Native", colour="Native"))+
     geom_spatvector(data = tdwg_level3_int, aes(fill="Introduced", colour="Introduced"))+
     scale_color_manual(values=colors)+
     scale_fill_manual(values=colors)+
     guides(color = "none")+ #This kills the "colour" legend, otherwise you get one for fill and one for colour
     theme(plot.background = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), panel.grid=element_line(colour="grey90"),
       legend.position = c(0.2, 0.25), legend.background = element_rect(fill = NA, color = NA), 
       legend.title=element_blank())
   ```

The full analysis (from when the shape is downloaded) ends up being:

```
tdwg_level3.shp <- vect(paste0(DataFP, "RandomCrap/tdwg wgsrpd master level3/level3.shp"))
tdwg_level3.shp <- crop(tdwg_level3.shp, extent(-179.9, 179.9, -90, 84))
tdwg_level3.shp.robinson <- project(tdwg_level3.shp,  "+proj=robin +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
tdwg_level3.shp.robinson <-tdwg_level3.shp.robinson[tdwg_level3.shp.robinson$LEVEL3_NAM != "Antarctica",]

tdwg_level3_nat <- tdwg_level3.shp.robinson[tdwg_level3.shp.robinson$LEVEL3_NAM %in% tdwg.native.name]
tdwg_level3_int <- tdwg_level3.shp.robinson[tdwg_level3.shp.robinson$LEVEL3_NAM %in% tdwg.introduced.name]

colors <- c("Native" = col.native, "Introduced" = col.introduced) #Create a "colours" item so it can be used in the legend

ggplot() + 
  geom_spatvector(data = tdwg_level3.shp.robinson, fill="grey70", colour="grey70")+
  geom_spatvector(data = tdwg_level3_nat, aes(fill="Native", colour="Native"))+
  geom_spatvector(data = tdwg_level3_int, aes(fill="Introduced", colour="Introduced"))+
  scale_color_manual(values=colors)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=colors)+
  guides(color = "none")+ #This kills the "colour" legend, otherwise you get one for fill and one for colour
  theme(plot.background = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), panel.grid=element_line(colour="grey90"),
        legend.position = c(0.2, 0.25), legend.background = element_rect(fill = NA, color = NA), 
        legend.title=element_blank())
```

(you could use the Valentin link to then get the exact grid lines you want etc)

[Final Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfM2H.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base-plot approach. This uses "terra 1.6.41" which is not on CRAN yet. You can install this version with it with `install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')`

```
library(terra)
#terra 1.6.41
library(geodata)
w <- world(path=".")
w <- w[w$NAME_0 != "Antarctica", ]
w <- project(w, "+proj=robin")

w$value <- NA
w$value[w$NAME_0 == "China"]<- "Native"
w$value[w$NAME_0 == "India"]<- "Introduced"

g <- graticule(60, seq(-60,90,30), crs="+proj=robin")

plot(g, mar=0, background="azure", col="light gray", lab.cex=.4, off.lat=-.1, retro=T, lab.lon=2:7)
plot(w, "value", colNA=gray(.9), add=TRUE, col=c("light blue", "light green"), plg=list(x=-13800000, y=-3200000, cex=.7))
```

[image]